# Setting HorizontalScrollView content width to multiple of parent width

Tags: android

Not sure how to approach this. I have a dialog design that contains a HorizontalScrollView and want the width of the contents of the HorizontalScrollView to be a set integer multiple of the HorizontalScrollView itself (which is fill_parent). Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: BTW, `fill_parent` is [deprecated after API level 8](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) and should be replaced by `match_parent` (essentially the same).

Comment: Always getting them mixed up :)

Comment: You can dynamically set the LayoutParams of the child views contained in the ScrollView once it has been created. You would just have to set the width of the params to `mHorizontalScrollView.getWidth() * multiple` where mHorizontalScrollView is an arbitrary name I gave to your ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks - at what point can I assume the width of the horizontal scroll view has been calculated within the dialog view layout? onCreateView or later in the lifecycle?

Comment: You can be sure that the view is ready in onStart. And just as a note if you want to tag me (or anyone else) in a comment to let them know you have responded just put @userName at the beginning of your comment :)

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks! Think I've got it now :)